# Why does my simple C# program quit immediately?

Tags: c#

I'm just starting out learning C#, and I'm working on a problem where I need to read a list of names (input by the user) and print them out again. I should accept up to 20 names. If the user enters null or QUIT, I should stop taking names.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = new string[20]; // create a 20 name array
            int nameCount = 0;
            string userInput;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a bunch of names!"); // ask for a name
            userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // store the name in userInput
            for (int maxNames = 20; maxNames < names.Length; maxNames++)
            {
                if (userInput == "") // if the entry is null, stop taking names.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", names);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (userInput == "QUIT") // if the entry is QUIT, stop taking names.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", names);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else // if it isn't null or QUIT, continue populating the array until we hit the max.
                {
                    names[nameCount] = userInput;
                    nameCount = nameCount + 1;
                    maxNames = maxNames + 1;
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the "Enter a bunch of names!" prompt, but as soon as I enter a name, the console closes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help for a newbie is appreciated.

Update: Thanks everybody for all the help. I took a few different pieces of advice (and new shortcuts!) and ended up with this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = new string[20]; // create a 20 name array
            int nameCount = 0;
            int maxNames = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a bunch of names!"); // ask for a name
            while (maxNames != 20)
            {
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // store the name in userInput
                if (userInput == "") // if the entry is null, stop taking names.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered:");
                    foreach (string name in names)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name);
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (userInput == "QUIT") // if the entry is QUIT, stop taking names.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered:");
                    foreach (string name in names)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name);
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                names[nameCount] = userInput;
                nameCount++;
                maxNames++;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading the console only once.
Put "userInput = Console.ReadLine()" inside the loop.

Comment: tried the code. The readline only accepts one input instead of 20.

Comment: There's also a problem with your `for` statement.  I'll leave you to work out what the issue is (it's a great learning experience!)

Comment: Clue: your initial conditions are incorrect

Comment: @TheGeneral hey, we have to start somewhere, right?  I was him 20 years ago and struggled with problems like this for *hours*.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: I modified your code and tested it. Please see my answer

Comment: IF you want to run something n times, what you should do, you have to start from some value and stop after n times? please check your for loop does that or not.

Comment: I also tested my answer, and it suffices with what you expect atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program ends inmmediately since it doesn't go inside the loop after getting the first input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> names = new List<string>(); // create a 20 name array
        string userInput;
        int maxNames = 0;
        while (maxNames != 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a bunch of names!"); // ask for a name
            userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // store the name in userInput
            names.Add(userInput);
            maxNames++;
            if(maxNames == 20 || userInput == "" || userInput == "QUIT")
            {
                foreach (string name in names)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

> I used a list of strings to store the user inputs, and wrote it after the the 'maxname' has been 20.

Comment: Thanks! Took a lot of examples from your snippet in my updated snippet. It works now!

Comment: Although a workable solution, in the future, I suggest you try to point out how / where the person's attempt failed so they understand WHY.   It's not good to just GIVE answers, but help educate the pitfall to prevent future :)  Descent answer though

Comment: I stated it on the first line of my answer @DRapp. But thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the community.  It appears so many are overlooking the very basic loop.

You declared your array to 20 names... No problem.

Then you have your for loop STARTING with a value of 20 which is already AT the length of the arrays.  Start your loop with 0.

```
for (int maxNames = 0; maxNames < names.Length; maxNames++)
{
   // Also, move your input WITHIN the loop
   userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // store the name in userInput

   if (userInput == "") // if the entry is null, stop taking names.
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", names);
      Console.ReadKey();
      break;
   }
   else if (userInput == "QUIT") // if the entry is QUIT, stop taking names.
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", names);
      Console.ReadKey();
      break;
   }
   else 
   // if it isn't null or QUIT, continue populating the array until we hit the max.
   {
      // since maxNames is now properly starting at 0,
      // you don't need your other name counter variable.
      // just use maxNames.  The loop process will increase it next cycle through
      names[maxNames] = userInput;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

At the  end after the for loop.

It auto closes when it finishes. By adding  Console.ReadLine(); at the end it will instruct it remain open

Comment: While your answer is a useful addition, it doesn't actually solve the problem.  He's asking why it is only prompting him once then closing - it should prompt him up to 20 times, but it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Between this and the other comments, I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `for` loop:

```
for (int maxNames = 20; maxNames < names.Length; maxNames++)
```

You initialize `maxNames` to 20, and then iterate as long as `maxNames < names.Length`.  From `string[] names = new string[20];` we know that `names.Length` is `20`, though, so before the first iteration the condition evaluates to `20 < 20`, which is, of course, `false`.  Thus, the loop is never entered and the program exits.  You probably meant to initialize `maxNames` to `0`, not `20`.